# SharePoint List Definition Instantiation Error (Cannot find a url for for quick launch element id 0, setting as ")

Tags: sharepoint

I’ve run a fairly complex list through SharePoint Solution Generator 2008 and have set it up as a WSPBuilder feature. The list definition project deploys and activates fine but when I try to create a list from it through the GUI it immediately takes me to an error page which has the following text:

**Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070909   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)**

And the log file contains the following messages:

**Creating list "GroupTaskList" in web "http://sharepoint2007:102" at URL "Lists/", (setuppath: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\Features\ GroupTaskListDefinition\GroupTaskList")
Creating List "GroupTaskList" for web "http://sharepoint2007:102", Feature 33b16b15-5b5c-4286-bc30-566d99d80861, Template Id 111116.**

**Standard 'verbose' messages**

**Cannot find a url for for quick launch element id 0, setting as ""
90009: Web http://sharepoint2007:102 is busy.  Please try again.
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x81070909
Application error when access /_layouts/new.aspx, Error=Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070909   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)**

**More standard 'verbose' messages**

The list does get created correctly but it does not have a valid URL associated to it and never shows up on the quick launch menu so I have to manually browse to http:--sharepoint2007:102/Lists/TheNameIGaveIt. I believe the  node in the schema.xml is correct because it’s being created and I have a QuickLaunchUrl tag which one of the errors is referring to as missing. That is the first major error in the log when I instantiate the list so I’m trying to find a solution to it and hopefully the others after it will go away.

```
<List QuickLaunchUrl="Lists/GroupTaskList" Name="GroupTaskList_FromTemplate" Title=" GroupTaskList_FromTemplate " Description=" GroupTaskList_FromTemplate Description" Direction="0" BaseType="0" Url="Lists/GroupTaskList_FromTemplate" VersioningEnabled="TRUE" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" FolderCreation="FALSE" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" Type="111116" Id="3fa08ec0-4772-4ab3-825c-00e1c335b31e" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
```

I can’t find any references to the errors in the log file on the net, has anyone run into this problem when instantiating a list definition in SharePoint 2007?

**Thanks in advance, Dan**

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but you could try removing the spaces in:

```
Title=" GroupTaskList_FromTemplate "
```

and

```
Description=" GroupTaskList_FromTemplate Description"
```

Have you tried that? The leading spaces may be throwing it off.

Also, look at the path in log file pointing to your feature ("\Template\Featueres\ GroupTaskListDefinition"). You've got a space in your path before " GroupTaskListDefinition".

Good Luck